# Extracting Contours from an image in OpenCV - Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have the following Image **result.png** with Countours drawn at every rectangle:
[image]

In the next step I am trying to extract only the inner portion of these rectangles to get the images which has centralised digits(2, 0, 1, 8). The code I am using is as follows:

```
import cv2

BLACK_THRESHOLD = 200
THIN_THRESHOLD = 10

im = cv2.imread('result.png', 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(im, 127, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 3)
idx = 0
for cnt in contours:
    idx += 1
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    roi = im[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    if h < THIN_THRESHOLD or w < THIN_THRESHOLD:
        continue
    cv2.imwrite(str(idx) + '.png', roi)
    cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (200, 0, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('img', im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

It is working but it is giving every possible cropped image on the basis of the Countours created as shown below(different image at each row):

[image]

It is extracting **18 Images** whereas I only want Images which has digits in its center without any kind of noise. Can anyone help me how to narrow this extraction process?

Comment: Use the hierarchy to stop when you've gone too deep.

Comment: Yes I read about that, but how to get the first innermost hierarchy level(index) of the contour while traversing different contours? @DanMašek

Comment: try using the flag `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` in the [findContours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) function

Comment: **contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 3)**
I changed the function to this as you said and I read that *it returns only extreme outer flags* but it is extracting only one image(i.e the original one on which contours are drawn)
As I am kind of new to OpenCv can you just run this on your machine and guide me?
PS: should I share the code through which contours are drawn?
 Thank You @api55

Comment: I'd think more using the RETR_TREE method, since those digits are nested in the boxes. The hierarchy you get out is a tree structure, so you can do depth first search and keep track of the current depth (or something along those lines). Then you'd just keep the contours at the appropriate level, and ignore the rest.

Comment: Okay how to apply Depth First Search in this? I mean what will be the nodes? Can you just give me a little more info? @DanMašek

Comment: Actually I noticed one thing that it is extracting Images irrespective of these contours by that i mean if there is no contour let us say around 2 then also it is extracting the image of 2 which should not happen.
@DanMašek